# Обращение к функции с аргументом message (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

День добрый. Пишу телеграм бота, тема такая: я создал инлайн кнопку 'Получать рассылку погоды' которая прикрепляется к сообщению и при нажатии кнопки, бот совершает, скажем так, действие. Я создал условие (в декораторе bot.callback_query_handler) при котором происходит обращение к функции (sending_forecast(message)), то есть к действию, если нажата кнопка. Проблема в том, что эта самая функция имеет аргумент message, которому, при обращении, нужно задать параметр, а какой параметр, я не знаю. Много чего писал туда - возвращается ошибка: объект не имеет атрибута 'chat'

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['info', 'start'])
def welcome(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
                #создание инлайн кнопки
        inline_mailing_forecast = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        inline_mailing_button = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Получать рассылку погоды', callback_data='subscribe_weather')
        inline_mailing_forecast.add(inline_mailing_button)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет, я бот, призванный облегчить наблюдение за погодой������. Напиши мне свой город и я расскажу, всё что знаю о нём))", reply_markup=inline_mailing_forecast)

#обратный вызов инлайн кнопки
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    if call.data == 'subscribe_weather':
        sending_forecast(message = )#какой параметр аргументу нужно задать?
 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def sending_forecast(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Какое-то действие')
```

Comment: `message` это скорее всего словарь. попробуйте `message['chat']['id']`

Comment: @5c0rp
Возвращается ошибка
`take_forecast(message['chat']['id'])
NameError: name 'message' is not defined`

Comment: @5c0rp, когда я обращаюсь к функции, то внутри скобок мой ide подсказывает переменную `message =`, а не просто `message`. Проблему мне удалось решить, положив весь код в класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

т.к. вы используете `callback_query_handler` объект `message` будет содержаться в `call`:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'subscribe_weather':
        sending_forecast(call.message)
    
def sending_forecast(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'sending_forecast Какое-то действие')
```