# Как при вводе команды /restart боту, бот перезапускался pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, telebot

Допустим у меня есть код:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help', 'restart'])
def send_welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введи Название объекта")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)


def process_name_step(message):
    try:
        service_data.update({'name': message.text})

        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите № работы в remedy(последние 6 цифр)")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_remedy_step)
    except Exception as e:
        bot.reply_to(message, 'oooops')
```

Когда я сейчас пишу ему во время заполнения `/start`, `/help` или `/restart` он не реагирует а просто продолжает дальше.
Как сделать проверку если пользователь напишет `/restart` он запускался заново?

Comment: укажите ос и тип запуска бота - служба, докер.. я правильно понял, что вы хотите перезапускать выполняемый скрипт с кодом бота при вводе команды в самом боте?

Comment: windows 10 я просто запускаю через pycharm и да вы правильно поняли

Comment: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/run-python-script-windows-service + `net stop ..., net start ...`, но имейте в виду, что вызов остановки (с последующим стартом) службы бота из самого бота может привести к остановке без запуска, т.к. процесс завершается. Посмотрите в сторону потоков на счёт этого

Comment: А если мне нужно что бы бот начинал заново в самом скрипте? Нет ли такой команды что бы можно было прописать в файле и он перезапустился?

Comment: что значит начинал заново в самом скрипте? вернулся на предыдущий шаг? вызвал функцию?

Comment: да вызвть функцию

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1234239/234134 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1230692/234134

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
@bot.message_handler(command=['restart'])
def test(m):
   bot.send_message(m.chat.id, "Рестарт") # Отправит сообщение в чат
   quit(os.system("python 'Путь к файлу'")) # Закроет и заново откроет файл (не работает в цикле)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать через много поточность. То есть при написании команды бот создаёт новый поток и убивает свой.